# Python Pandas user friendly table display

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Still learning python and pandas and having trouble with data display.  I have a dataframe that contains an owner id in one column, and a list of dictionaries in another column.  I would like to create a more user friendly dataframe that displays (exports to excel) select key values pairs based on owner id.

current df1:

```
   owner id |   players
     1234   |   [{height: 7", weight: 500lbs, other data: not important}, {height: 6", weight" 400lbs, other data: not important}]
     4567   |   [{height: 10", weight: 100lbs, other data: not important}, {height: 4", weight" 50lbs, other data: not important}]
```

desired dataframe:

```
 owner id |  height  |  weight 
    1234  |   7"     |  500lbs
          |   6"     |  400lbs
    4567  |  10"     |  100lbs
          |   4"     |   50lbs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to unravel the list into multiple rows with other columns values repeated. Then you can convert the dictionary to columns using apply [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) or [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html). Then apply [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to get the data in the desired format

##### Creating data

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'owner_id' : [1234,5678],
    'players' : [[{"height": '7"', "weight": '500lbs', "other data": 'not important'}, {"height": '6"', "weight" : '400lbs', "other data": 'not important'}], [{"height": '10"', "weight": '100lbs', "other data": 'not important'}, {"height": '4"', "weight" : '50lbs', "other data": 'not important'}]]
    })
```

##### Pre-processing

```
df1 = df1.explode('players')      
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df1.pop("players").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

##### Generating data

```
df1.set_index(['owner_id'])[['weight']]
```

##### Output :

This gives us the expected output

```
owner_id height  weight                      
1234     7"      500lbs 
         6"      400lbs
5678     10"     100lbs
         4"       50lbs
```

Answer (score 1):

If your element in the "players" column is a list you can first explode it and then apply a series to the dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([df.drop(['players'], axis=1), df['players'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Output:
|owner_id | height | weight|
|---------|--------|-------|
|0 |1   |7  |500lbs|
|1  |2  |6  |400lbs|

Answer (score 0):

[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df2 = df.explode('players')
df2 = df2.join(pd.json_normalize(df2.pop('players'))[['height', 'weight']])
```

output:

```
   owner id height  weight
0      1234      7  500lbs
0      1234      7  500lbs
1      4567      6  400lbs
1      4567      6  400lbs
```